# What's wrong with my implementation of POJ 1007?

Tags: c

Hi I'm new to competitive programming and this is my first problem. (Here's the link this problem - : [POJ 1007 -- DNA Sorting](http://poj.org/problem?id=1007)). The problem is basically simple string manipulation and here's the solution that I've come up with.

```
    // POJ id=1007 - DNA
#include<stdio.h>
int a[50][100];
void insert(char temp[], int i)
{
  int j=0;
  while(temp[j]!='\0')
  {
    switch(temp[j])
    {
     case 'A':
       a[i][j]=0;
       break;
     case 'C':
       a[i][j]=1;
       break;
     case 'G':
       a[i][j]=2;
       break;
     case 'T':
       a[i][j]=3;
       break;
     }
   j++;
 }  
}
int main()
{
 int i,j,unso[100],k,m,n,large,largeindex=0;
 scanf("%d%d", &n, &m); // n -length 50max|| m - number of strings 100max
 char temp[50];
 char dna[50][100];
 for(i=0;i<m;i++)
  {
    gets(dna[i]);
    gets(temp);
    insert(temp,i);
    }   // Inserted the string as an equivalent integer array


  // HERE: Calculate measure of ``unsortedness'' for ith string and put it in unso[i] for all 0<=i<n
  for(j=0;j<n;j++)
   for(i=0;i<m;i++)
     for(k=i+1;k<m-1;k++)
       if(a[j][i]<a[j][k])
         unso[j]++;



  // HERE: Find the largest element in anso, note the corresponding 'i', print dna[i][100];
  i=0;
  do{
  large=unso[0];
   for(j=1;j<m;j++)
   {
    if(unso[j]>large){
     large=unso[j];
     largeindex=j;}
   }
   printf ("%s" , dna[j]);
   unso[j]=0;
   largeindex=0;
   i++;
   }while(i<m);

return 0;
}
```

Please help to find what's wrong with my implementation.

Comment: First thing: to hold a string with 50 characters you need an array with 51 elements.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that.:) Can you think of another mistake?. The program is not running for the sample inputs given in the problem.

Comment: Check `scanf()` results.  Post your sample inputs/outputs and expected output.